# motherboard died, not replacing.. how do i mount SCSI drives and recover data?

Tags: scsi

I have an old IBM x206 with Ultra 320 SCSI drives, the motherboard died and Im not replacing it but the data on the drives is still important.

I dont have another similar server to hand, is there some kind of enclosure / caddy that can read SCSI drives

Any product suggestions or alternate ways to read data from SCSI drives appreciated.
Obvioulsy the cheaper the solution the better as I cant get any budget for third party recovery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the drives are not in any kind of raid config the cheapest option is to just buy a used scsi controller, likely you can snag one for under $50 off ebay, plug it in to a PC and migrate your data off.

Comment: If the drives were hot swap you'll probably also need an SCA-LVD adapter to convert the 80 pin hot swap connector to 68 pin which you can use with a regular internal SCSI controller.

Comment: Yes the drives are hot swap and also RAID in this case just a mirror so a single drive solution via a used controller and adaptor should be fine, but what about RAID 5 arrays which I have lots of?

Comment: Depending on the raid 5 arrays you can sometimes just replace the controller with the same model controller and you'll be fine. If its a funky onboard controller you'll likely just need to get a whole new  motherboard if you cant find a card to match.